# Sum all columns whose names start with a pattern, by group

Tags: r, rowsum

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to sum columns by groups based on their names. I have a data frame like this one:

```
DT <- data.frame(a011=c(0,10,20,0),a012=c(010,10,0,0),a013=c(10,30,0,10),
a021=c(10,20,20,10),a022=c(0,0,0,10),a023=c(20,0,0,0),a031=c(30,0,10,0),
a032=c(0,0,10,0),a033=c(20,0,0,0))
```

I would like to obtain the sum of all the columns starting with "a01", of all the columns starting with "a02" and all the columns starting with "a03":

```
a01tot a02tot a03tot
    20     30     50
    50     20      0
    20     20     20
    10     20      0
```

So far I have used

```
DT$a01tot <- rowSums(DT[,grep("a01", names(DT))])
```

and so on, but my real data frame has many more groups and I would like to avoid having to write a line of code for each group. I was wondering if it is possible to include "a01","a02","a03"... in a vector or list and have something that adds the columns "a01tot","a02tot","a03tot"... to the data frame automatically.

I know that my question is very similar to this one: [R sum of rows for different group of columns that start with similar string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384221/r-sum-of-rows-for-different-group-of-columns-that-start-with-similar-string), but the solution pointed out there,

```
cbind(df, t(rowsum(t(df), sub("_.*", "_t", names(df)))))
```

does not work in my case because there isn't a common element (like "_") to replace (I cannot change the names of the variables to a01_1, a02_2 etc.).

Switching to the "long" format is not a viable solution in my case either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can store the patterns in a vector and loop through them.  With your example you can use something like this:

```
patterns <- unique(substr(names(DT), 1, 3))  # store patterns in a vector
new <- sapply(patterns, function(xx) rowSums(DT[,grep(xx, names(DT)), drop=FALSE]))  # loop through
#     a01 a02 a03
#[1,]  20  30  50
#[2,]  50  20   0
#[3,]  20  20  20
#[4,]  10  20   0
```

You can adjust the names like this:

```
colnames(new) <- paste0(colnames(new), "tot")  # rename
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine with my example. When I try to apply it to the real data, though, I get an error in rowSums: " 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions". This seems to be because for one of the "groups" there is only one column, so rowSums gets a vector instead of a data frame. How could I solve this?

Comment: @Astarte you can get around that issue by adding `drop = FALSE`.  I edited the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2) 
library(tidyr)

DT %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = c('id')) %>% 
  mutate(Group = substr(variable, 1, 3)) %>% 
  group_by(id, Group) %>% 
  summarise(tot = sum(value)) %>% 
  spread(Group, tot) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Results

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

  a01 a02 a03
1  20  30  50
2  50  20   0
3  20  20  20
4  10  20   0
```

Then as @Jota suggests `colnames(new) <- paste0(colnames(new), "tot")`

Comment: May I recommend `gather()` from `tidyr` instead of `melt`. Reshape2 is a thing of the past :)

Comment: @FelipeGerard Actually I was just using `reshape2` again and it is still amazing when you are reshaping a lot of variables. It is very good at guessing names and so on. I think it's still in the game!

Comment: I don't doubt it! Have you used `tidyr`'s `select`-like selectors? They're amazing!